# "Она прекрасна(,) значит () не умна" - как расставить знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Обсуждалось на одном форуме (хотелось бы узнать правильный ответ).
Имеем предложение: "Она прекрасна() значит() не умна". Автор вопроса предложил несколько вариантов расстановки знаков препинания:
*«Она прекрасна, значит не умна».

«Она прекрасна, значит, не умна».

«Она прекрасна, значит — не умна».

«Она прекрасна — значит не умна».

«Она прекрасна — значит, не умна».

«Она прекрасна — значит — не умна».*
Какой из перечисленных вариантов правильный? Или, может быть, тут несколько вариантов имеют право на существование?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выберем  такие варианты: 
(1) «Она прекрасна — значит, (она) не умна».

Это БСП с причинно-следственными отношениями (или другими зависимыми отношениями, например: факт - вывод). Второе предложение неполное.

Вводное слово ЗНАЧИТ (=следовательно)обособляем.

(2) «Она прекрасна, значит, не умна».

Это простое предложение с однородными сказуемыми, но при этом они осложнены добавочным значением обусловленности, которое выражает вводное слово ЗНАЧИТ.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ/ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Мне хочется немного дополнить ответ для окончательной ясности. Откуда вообще взялась такая задача?. Дело в том, что  слово ЗНАЧИТ может выполнять следующие функции: а) глагол; б) слово-связка, 3) вводное слово; 4) вводное слово в составе подчинительного союза. Разобраться в этой грамматике непросто даже специалистам, а остальные пользователи ставят знаки препинания наугад, по интуиции.

Поэтому нужно было выбрать среди этого набора вариантов те, в которых прочитывается грамматика и смысл. Общий принцип таков: разные оттенки авторской семантики (содержание) соотносятся с разной грамматической и интонационной формой, а ЗАТЕМ обозначаются знаками препинания (ни в коем случае не наоборот!).

Я предполагаю два варианта решения: 1) обозначаем обусловленность двух частей предложения, разделительная интонация, БСП → ставим тире. 2) не обозначаем такую обусловленность, перечислительная интонация, простое предложение с однородными сказуемыми → ставим запятую. А со словом ЗНАЧИТ что делать? Как определить его функцию?

Надо сказать, что грамматическая наука не стоит на месте, люди работают и предлагают интересные решения, одним из которых мы здесь воспользуемся. Среди средств связи, которые используются в предложениях с однородными членами и в сложных предложениях, выделяются ОСНОВНЫЕ И ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНЫЕ (их называют структурными элементами). Основные средства связи (союзы, бессоюзная  связь) задают вид грамматической формы, а структурные элементы (наречия, частицы, вводные слова) уточняют вид связи, причем иногда очень существенно.

(1) «Она прекрасна — значит, (она) не умна». В данном БСП основным видом связи является разделительная связь (интонационно это две фразы, разделенные паузой), вводное слово ЗНАЧИТ конкретизирует её как "факт - вывод"

(2) «Она прекрасна, значит, не умна». В простом предложении с однородными членами основным видом связи является сочинительная связь и интонация перечисления, вводное слово ЗНАЧИТ выполняет более серьезную функцию, обозначая обусловленность (фактическую неоднородность) сказуемых.

Answer (score 4):

В настоящее время сосуществуют два подхода к слову *значит*.

1.***Значит* - вводное слово.** Варианты:

*Она прекрасна, значит, не умна.*

*Она прекрасна — значит, не умна.*

*Она прекрасна, значит — не умна.*

2.***Значит* - союз.** Варианты:

*Она прекрасна, значит не умна.*

*Она прекрасна, значит — не умна.*

*Она прекрасна — значит не умна.* (Вариант авторский, перед союзом тире нежелательно.)

Вариант *Она прекрасна — значит — не умна* неоправдан. С помощью тире выделяются только распространенные вводные предложения, а не вводные слова. Тем  более не выделяются с помощью тире союзы.

Видимо, автор имел в виду тенденцию СМИ - постановку тире вместо запятых. Но в данном случае тенденция не работает.

Comment: Непонятна структура вашего множества одобренных предложений. Это простые предложения с однородными сказуемыми или сложные предложения (БСП, СПП)? Какова роль союза ЗНАЧИТ?
Обычно  вводное слово ЗНАЧИТ входит в состав двойного союза: ЕСЛИ…ЗНАЧИТ (с запятой).

Comment: "Словарь вводных слов": "значит" в функции союза (= следовательно)
соединяет части сложносочиненного предложения
(с оттенком значения следствия) или однородные члены предложения. Употребляется как часть двойного подчинительного
союза «если... значит» в сложных предложениях
с придаточным условия, не обособляется.

Comment: Но "Справочник по пунктуации" рекомендует запятую ставить: союз "значит" соединяет предложения или части сложного предложения  (в том числе в составе двойного союза «если... значит» или «раз... значит»). Сближаясь по значению с вводными словами «следовательно», «таким образом», союз «значит» отделяется запятой (реже тире) от последующей части предложения.

Comment: Если в предложении используется союз, то это СПП? Три ваших предложения с союзом ЗНАЧИТ - это  всё СПП? (Есть у меня такой справочник, только грамматику сложно по нему изучать). Насколько я понимаю, главное в этом примере - это определить синтаксис, то есть объяснить знаки препинания, а не просто расставить их.

Comment: Получается, что ССП с оттенком значения следствия, а союз сочинительный.

Comment: У глагола  «получиться»  несколько значений: появиться,  стать, сделаться, случиться. Неужели они имеют отношение к грамматическому анализу? И еще вот что интересно. В русской пунктуации действует семантический принцип, из чего следует, что предложенное высказывание имеет шесть оттенков смысла , выраженных в шести разных формах?

Comment: >то предложенное высказывание имеет шесть оттенков смысла , выраженных в шести разных формах?

"Она прекрасна, значит не умна" - она прекрасна, поэтому неумна   
"Она прекрасна, значит, не умна" - она прекрасна и неумна.   
"Она прекрасна, значит — не умна" - Её называют прекрасной, она неумна.  
"Она прекрасна — значит не умна" - она прекрасна, поэтому наверняка неумна.  
«Она прекрасна — значит, не умна». - Она прекрасна, её называют неумной.

Comment: Марк Из, здесь ОДИН СМЫСЛ. Некто видит красивую девушку (факт) и предполагает, что она не умна, то есть не отличается большим умом (вывод). Потому что ум и красота, по его мнению, несовместимы. Это всё. Дальше грамматические и интонационные тонкости: сделать / не сделать паузу, подчеркнуть/не подчеркивать обусловленность. А слитное написание "неумный" здесь вообще неприемлемо, потому что "неумный" - это "довольно глупый", а такой вывод можно сделать только после некоторого знакомства с предметом.

Comment: >Дальше грамматические и интонационные тонкости: сделать / не сделать паузу

@София, как раз сделать или не сделать паузу подсказывает пунктуация: запятая - короткая пауза, тире - длинная (знаю, что это не всегда так, но не в данном случае).

Знаки показывают нам к чему относится вводное слово "значит": к первой части предложения (3), ко второй (5) или к обеим сразу (2).

В случае же с союзом, знаки показывают степень противопоставления первой и второй части предложения: сильное (4) или слабое (1).